# Why is the light of Eärendil the Elves' most beloved star?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Wasn't Eärendil a mortal man? So why would he be most beloved to Elves?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Eärendil was *half*-Elven, who chose to be an Elf.

Why would his star have been particularly beloved?

1. It was actually one of the Silmarils, the last true light of the Two Trees of Valinor, which the Noldor had fought and died to recover.
2. It was a sign from the Valar: after hundreds of years of despair and defeat against Morgoth, the Star of Eärendil was a symbol that the Valar (and Eru) were still with them, and a reminder of the War of Wrath in which Morgoth was utterly defeated and the Elves freed from his domination of Middle-earth.

Comment: I'm not sure if he was 'utterly defeated', his evil still lived on.

Comment: But he himself was utterly defeated. If I was immortal, in a locked room with no light for the rest of time with no way out, I'd consider myself "utterly defeated" as my very existence would be completely pointless. How would you feel if you meant less to the world than a leaf that falls from a tree? At least that served a purpose...

Comment: The whole world might be Morgoth's Ring, but Morgoth himself was executed and forcibly ejected from the world. No greater victory was possible without breaking the world.

Comment: @John Bell - Still less pointless than an existence of a mortal.

Comment: A brief explanation why the light of the two trees "matters".

Comment: @Yakk TLDR: The trees were the only sources of light (except for the stars) for the first elves. They were created by the Valar without the influence of Morgoth, and so in-universe basically represented ultimate purity. It's their light that was in the Silmarils, which ultimately shaped most First Age history.

Comment: @JohnRobinson Yes, I know.  I was suggesting such a brief bit be added to the answer.  I, however, apparently forgot that clause.  Pretend my previous comment starts with "This answer would be improved by ".  Sigh.